# Determine the number of orbits of the action $B\cdot A := B^TAB$ of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ on the symmetric $n\times n$ matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, group-theory, symmetric-matrices

Determine the number of orbits of the left action $B\cdot A := B^TAB$ of $GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ on the set $Sym_n(\mathbb{R})$ symmetric $n\times n$ matrices with entries from $\mathbb{R}$.

I'm looking for a hint or a starting point. I'm a little rusty on my linear algebra. I'm guessing the spectral theorem comes into play somehow..

Comment: This is basically [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).

Comment: That is interesting. I'm not exactly sure how to use that to form a solution.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment says, this amounts to [Sylvester's law of inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia).

Sylvester's law of inertia states that two matrices occupy the same orbit if and only if they have the same "inertia".  Thus, the number of orbits is the total possible number of "innertiae" $(n_+,n_-,n_0)$ (with $n_+ + n_- + n_0 = n$).

Via the ["stars and bars" formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two), we find that the total number of orbits is
$$
\binom{n+3-1}{3-1} = \binom{n+2}2.
$$